# Strange behaviour in FIFO Sqs and AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

There are around 20K messages in the backlog for the fifo queue . Lambda is the consumer for the fifo queue . One source is pushing messages to the  FIFO  queue with group id - Group1 .

There was a retryable exception being thrown from the  lambda code hence the entire batch would be reprocessed. but now when i run my cucumber test cases with a different message group id i.e Group2 . As per my expectation the Group2 messages should have been processed parallelly . But looks like they are getting processed at all .

Is my understanding correct , multiple group ids should be processed parallelly by lambda ,but looks like its not happening .

Comment: For FIFO queues, there can be a maximum of 20,000 inflight messages (received from a queue by a consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue). If you reach this quota, Amazon SQS returns no error messages. If your queue has a large backlog of 20,000 or more messages with the same message group ID, FIFO queues might be unable to return the messages that have a different message group ID but were sent to the queue at a later time until you successfully consume the messages from the backlog.

Comment: Cool ..makes sense ..i still have around 1k more messages for the same message group id ..will verify once the back log reaches less than 20 k . thanks Mohamed.

Comment: thank you working now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FIFO queues, there can be a maximum of 20,000 inflight messages (received from a queue by a consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue). If you reach this quota, Amazon SQS returns no error messages. If your queue has a large backlog of 20,000 or more messages with the same message group ID, FIFO queues might be unable to return the messages that have a different message group ID but were sent to the queue at a later time until you successfully consume the messages from the backlog